# Provide a modified "PATH" variable at Eclipse startup

Tags: java, eclipse

I have an Eclipse product which reads a certain property from the System "path" variable to execute a certain functionality. The path to the executable which executes this functionality should be present in the "path" variable. However, I do not want to modify the path variable in the Advanced System settings of the user's computer who uses my product manually or during installation of the product. I want this path to be available to my product during start up, which in turn is available for all the processes and tools that run from within this Eclipse instance until the instance is alive. One way to achieve this is to start my Eclipse product from within a Windows batch file which sets the path variable and then launches the Eclipse product as below.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\path to my executable;%path%
start myeclipseproduct.exe
```

However, I do not want the user of my product to execute a batch file to start my product.
Is there a way to set the path variable via eclipse.ini file or config.ini **or** to execute a batch file from the eclipse.ini or config.ini that sets the modified path variable which is available for the entire eclipse instance?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So, you want to ship a `JRE` with your product ? =)

Comment: How will you know the path of the command? If you know the path, why can't you execute it directly using Runtime command with the complete path.
If your product depends on some external program, then that is the pre-requisite the user should have it installed before using your program or else package the required program along with your product.

Comment: You can set system properties in the eclipse.ini but you can't modify the path. Does this value have to be in the path?

Comment: Yes, we do ship jre along with the product, but the path is provided via -vm parameter in eclipse.ini file.

Comment: I know the path that needs to be provided to the third party tool that is integrated with our eclipse product. Also, we want to avoid modifying the path variable during the product installation and make it available only during runtime.

Comment: Is there a way to trigger a batch file on clicking the eclipse.exe  and before the jvm is launched?